# "Converse" of Taylor's theorem

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, real-analysis

Let $f:(a,b)\to\mathbb{R}$. We are given $(k+1)$ continuous functions $a_0,a_1,\ldots,a_k:(a,b)\to\mathbb{R}$ such that for every $c\in(a,b)$ we can write $f(c+t)=\sum_{i=0}^k a_i(c)t^i+o(t^k)$ (for any $t$ in a neighbourhood of $0$). Can we conclude that $f$ is of class $C^k$?

Comment: Have you tried doing this for $k = 0$ and $k = 1$?

Comment: This question is really more suitable for math.stackexchange.com than here.

Comment: I know, but there nobody could answer. Btw yes, if $k\ge 1$, it is easy to check that $f$ is of class $C^1$.

Comment: Yes, I spoke too soon. Nice answer by Pietro.

Comment: Also, I seem to recall that is is important that these are functions on a whole interval.  Doing this at one point is not enough to show the function is $k$ times differentiable at that point.

Comment: right, for instance $f(t):=t^{k+1}\chi_{\mathbb{Q}}(t)$ is $o(t^k)$ for $t\to 0$ but it is only differentiable at $0$.

Comment: @carizio If you want to merge, see http://mathoverflow.net/help/merging-accounts

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Yes. It's a classical result that goes back to Marcinkiewicz and Zygmund (*On the differentiability of functions and summability of trigonometric series*, Fund.Math **26** (1936) ).

There is a sublety in the form of the remainder: a first and natural characterization of $C^k$ is obtained asking a remainder of the form $t^k \sigma(c,t)$ with $\sigma$ continuous in the pair $(c,t)$ and $\sigma(c,0)=0$ (i.e. the remainder is "$o(t^k)$ locally uniformly wrto $c$"). In this form, the proof is very easy, even for vector valued functions of several variables.

But one may state a characterization of $C^k(a,b)$ asking (seemengly) less, that is, for any $c\in(a,b)$ the remainder at $c$ is just $o(t^k)$: it is true, but not a trivial fact, that then the remainder necessarily has the preceding form, so one gets a characterization as well (this is a successive result and I'll add references to it as soon as I recall it; or maybe somebody can do it for me).

**edit.** Given the origin of the question, I'll leave some hints for an elementary proof of: $f\in C^k(a,b)$ if and only $f$ has a polynomial expansion of order $k$ with continuous coefficients  $a_i\in C^0(a,b)$ and remainder of the form 
$$f(c+t) - \sum_{j=0}^k \frac{a_j(c)}{j!}t^j = t^k\sigma(c,t)\, ,$$
with a continuous $\sigma(c,t)$ vanishing identically for $t=0$.
One implication is given of course by the Taylor theorem; for the other let $A_0,\dots,A_k$ be antiderivatives of $a_0=f,a_1, \dots a_k$. Fix $a < x < y < b$ and consider the function:

$$\phi(t):=A_0(y+t)- A_0(x+t) = \int_x^y f(c + t) dc\, .$$
Find *two* polynomial expansions of order $k$ for the function $\phi$ at zero (you can integrate the polynomial expansion for $f(t+c)$ either wrto $c$ or wrto $t$, this is the idea!). Then use the unicity of polynomial expansions (that is, if a polynomial $P(t)$ of degree not larger than $k$ is  $o(t^k)$ for $t\to0$, then it is the zero polynomial), and deduce $A_j(y)-A_j(x) = a_{j-1}(y) - a_{j-1}(x)$. Since $x$ and $y$ are arbitrary, the thesis follows with $f ^{(j)} = a_0^{(j)} = a_j  $.

Comment: The Marcinkiweicz & Zygmund paper is [available from EUDML](https://eudml.org/doc/212834), but I can't find the appropriate theorem in it (as I mentioned in my answer I could find it in a later paper by Oliver, however): all conclusions seem to be "almost everywhere" (e.g., theorem 1).  Did I miss something, or were you perhaps thinking of a different paper?

Comment: According to Abraham & Robbin's *Transversal mapping and flows* the result (with the local uniform assumption on the remainder) is due to  Marcinkiweicz & Zygmund; but I could have copied the reference wrongly. My fault. The above proof is just home-made.

Answer (score 12):

I was unable to get my hands on the book by Abraham & Robbin mentioned in the answer by Benoit Jubin, nor locate the exact statement in the paper by Marcinkiewicz & Zygmund mentioned in the answer by Pietro Majer (every theorem in this paper, as well as a later related solo paper by Marcinkiewicz, "Sur les séries de Fourier", *Fund. Math.* **27** (1937) 38–69, seems to have "almost everywhere" in the conclusion).

However, the keyword is "de la Vallée-Poussin derivative" or "Peano derivative" to designate the $k$-th coefficient of an asymptotic expansion of $f$ around a point: i.e., if $f(a+h) = f(a) + f_{1}(a)\,h + \cdots + \frac{1}{n!} f_{n}(a)\,h^n + o(h^n)$ (with no assumption of uniformity w.r.t. $a$ on the error term), we say that $f_{k}(a)$ is the $k$-th dlVP/Peano derivative of $f$ at $a$.  Given this, is fairly easy to use Google to find a theorem in the literature that answers the question and much more:

H. William Oliver, "[The Exact Peano Derivative](http://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1954-076-03/S0002-9947-1954-0062207-1/S0002-9947-1954-0062207-1.pdf)", *Trans. Amer. Math. Soc.* **76** (1954) 444–456: theorem 3:

> If $f_n(x)$ exists and is bounded above or below throughout $[a,b]$, then $f_n(x) = f^{(n)}(x)$, the ordinary $n$-th derivative, at every point $x \in [a,b]$.

The same paper proves various other interesting properties of these dlVP/Peano derivatives: they are Baire class 1, have the Darboux property (=intermediate values property), satisfy a mean value theorem (stated in the paper) and have the Denjoy property (=the inverse image of an open interval is either empty or has positive measure).

The proofs in Oliver's paper involves rather tedious case distinctions.  A different, and possibly simpler, proof of the above-quoted statement is given in: Verblunsky, "[On the Peano Derivatives](http://plms.oxfordjournals.org/content/s3-22/2/313.full.pdf+html)", *Proc. London Math. Soc.* **22** (1971) 313–324 (see theorem 1(ii)).

Analogous properties for *approximate* Peano derivatives (same definition as above except that the asymptotic expansion is only assumed on a set of $h$ having density $1$ at $0$) are proved in Babcock, "[On Properties of the Approximate Peano Derivatives](http://www.jstor.org/stable/1998625)", *Trans. Amer. Math. Soc.* **212** (1975) 279–294.

Answer (score 5):

Here is the answer I posted on https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/876071/multiple-differentiability-from-taylor-expansion, before seeing the question here.

This question is answered in the affirmative in Abraham, Robbin, Transversal mappings and flows, Ch.1, $\S2$, A criterion for smoothness. They prove this converse to Taylor's theorem for functions between Banach spaces and attribute the one-dimensional case to Marcinkiewicz, Zygmund, On the differentiability of functions and summability of trigonometrical series.

As I understand after a glimpse at the proof, they prove by induction that $a_j=f^{(j)}$ by proving that $a_j(c+h)−a_j(c)=\int_0^1 a_{j+1}(c+th)h\,dt$. To prove that $f$ is $C^k$ and thus to justify the above, they prove that $a_1$ satisfies the hypothesis of the theorem with $k$ replaced by $k−1$ and then use induction (in the finite dimensional case; a trick using Hahn-Banach permits to reduce the theorem to that case). The proof of that fact looks elementary but tricky; in particular, they use a polynomial interpolation lemma.

Comment: Note that the proof for functions between Banach spaces follows easily from the case of functions between finite dimensional spaces, as shown in Abraham-Robbin. However, the finite dimensional case has a two lines proof (compare with the proof in A-R, several pages of hard analysis via partitions of unity!). Mollify, use the uniqueness of polynomial expansion, apply the theorem of limit under the sign of derivative.

Answer (score 4):

Another answer: You are prescribing a Whitney jet, and the Whitney extension theorem gives the answer:

- Whitney, Hassler: Analytic extensions of differentiable functions defined in closed sets, Trans. AMS 36 (1934), 63--89.

Also, another reference building on the paper of Marcinkiewicz and Zygmund, is

- G. Glaeser: Etude de quelques Algebres Tayloriennes, J. Anal. Math. 11 (1958), 1-118.